# virt-install fails to connect to socket

Tags: libvirt

I'm following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/max-i-mil/f44e8e6f2416d88055fc2d0f36c6173b) to run multiple VMs on mac os with apple m1.

I got the following error:

```
sudo virt-install \
--name host1 \
--memory 2048 \
--vcpus 2 \
--disk size=30 \
--cdrom ./box.img \
--os-variant ubuntu22.04 \
--virt-type hvf \
--qemu-commandline='-M highmem=off -netdev vmnet-shared,id=net0 -device virtio-net-device,netdev=net0,mac=54:54:00:55:54:51' \
--network user
Password:
WARNING  CDROM media does not print to the text console by default, so you likely will not see text install output. You might want to use --location. See the man page for examples of using --location with CDROM media

Starting install...
Allocating 'host1.qcow2'                                                                                |    0 B  00:00:00 ...
Removing disk 'host1.qcow2'                                                                             |    0 B  00:00:00
ERROR    Failed to connect socket to '/opt/homebrew/var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock': No such file or directory
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start host1
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

apparently it's not there:

```
$ ls -al /opt/homebrew/var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock
ls: /opt/homebrew/var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock: No such file or directory
```

but libvirt is up and running:

```
$ brew services list                            130
Name             Status  User File
libvirt          started root ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.libvirt.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it has been sometime since this question was posted but I wanted to update here for anyone looking that had the same problem, the guide being referenced here has been updated with a fix in the footer.

**Manually start virtlogd**

When starting libvirt - the expectation was that libvirt would manage virtlogd, which is used to manage logs from VMs as an alternative to writing them all to a file which need manual disk management.

Error:

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Failed to connect socket to '/opt/homebrew/var/run/libvirt/virtlogd-sock': No such file or directory
```

Fix:

```
sudo /opt/homebrew/sbin/virtlogd -d
```

This will start virlodg as a daemon process manually

See here:

https://gist.github.com/max-i-mil/f44e8e6f2416d88055fc2d0f36c6173b#2---manually-start-virtlogd